# SQL / Teradata - How can I get the most recent record from one table RELEVANT TO A DATE COLUMN IN ANOTHER TABLE?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables below. I want to make a query that checks for any given date (let's say 7 days after A.Date_Added), I want to see what the ID's current status is as per Table B. **So, 7 days after A.Date_Added, what was the most recent status for each ID?** Eventually I want to do this for 30 days, 60 days, etc, but just the logic for 7 days could be applied to all.

**Table A:**

| ID | Date_Added |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/04/2019 |
| 2 | 01/05/2020 |
| 3 | 03/04/2020 |

**Table B:**

| ID | Date_of_Status_Change | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/06/2020 | Happy |
| 1 | 01/08/2020 | Sad |
| 1 | 02/12/2020 | Angry |
| 2 | 01/07/2020 | Sad |
| 2 | 01/11/2020 | Angry |
| 2 | 02/24/2020 | Sad |
| 3 | 03/05/2020 | Happy |
| 3 | 03/08/2020 | Confused |

**End Result:**

| ID | Date_Added | Status_Seven_Days_After_Added |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/04/2019 | Happy |
| 2 | 01/05/2020 | Angry |
| 3 | 03/04/2020 | Confused |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.ID, a.Date_Added, b.Status
from tableA as a
join tableB as b
  on a.ID = b.ID 
  -- 7 days after A.Date_Added
 and b.Date_of_Status_Change between a.Date_Added and a.Date_Added +7
qualify
   row_number(*) -- most recent status for each ID
   over (partition by a.ID
         order by b.Date_of_Status_Change desc) = 1
```

You might want to switch to a Left Join if there are no matching rows for an ID.

Comment: I have used your answers on the Teradata forums SO many times you have no idea. I did not expect to get an answer from you- you're kind of an internet celebrity at my workplace. I appreciate your help so much :)